# Upload Base64 Video to Parse.com - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, video-capture

I'm trying to get my base64 video data to save to Parse.com. I'm using the same technique for images and it works fine, but video will not save for some reason. I've have been trying to debug this issue for weeks with no success. I basically copied the technique/code after I had images working this way... using base64 I figured it would be more or less work the same...

My video data looks like this:

```
data:video/3gpp;base64,AAAAGGZ0eXAzZ3A0AAAAAGlzb2.....
```

The video being saved is only ~56kb - ~1mb. Saving to Parse.com which has a 10mb file limit. I've checked my data and everything seems right, right up until I try to save the file to Parse.com, which spits back an error 400.

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/files/myVideo.3gp 400 (Bad Request)
```

along with this in my XHR Response :

```
{"code":107,"error":"base64 field cannot be decoded"}
```

Anyone have any insight as to why it may not be working:

```
var videoFile = new Parse.File('myVideo.3gp', {
    base64: _params.videoData
});

// save the parse file
videoFile
    .save({
        success: function(resp) {
            window.ERROR = "Success: " + resp;
        },
        error: function(e, r) {
            window.ERROR = "Error: " + e + " : " + r;
        }
    })
    .then(function() {

        _params.videoData = null;

        // create object to hold caption and file reference
        var videoObject = new ImageObject();

        // set object properties
        videoObject.set('title', _params.title);
        videoObject.set('user', Parse.User.current());
        videoObject.set('img', videoFile);

        if (_params.location !== undefined) {
            videoObject.set('location', new Parse.GeoPoint(_params.location.latitude, _params.location.longitude));
        }

        // save object to parse backend
        videoObject
            .save()
            .then(function(resp) {
                console.log('Posted Video', resp);
                // Add User QtdPhoto
                defer.resolve(resp);
            });

    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Error', error);
        defer.reject(error);
    });
```

Comment: "not save for some reason" suggests you haven't done much debugging (if any). You should. And, yes, it's probably the same as pictures except that videos are way larger and base64-encoding them will make them even larger. If the browser doesn't crash, you may hit server-side limits.

Comment: compare docs  https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.File.html  to what you are providing to the File constructor. your data property does not seem to match the docs.

Comment: Can you also add the value of your `_params` here?

Answer (score 0):

---

HTTP Status code 400 means that your [request is not formed correctly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1). Can you copy-paste the actual HTTP request that is being made from DevTools or Firebug.

On the other note, if the request is being cut off after exactly the same amount of length. It may be caused by a firewall/router on your side of the equation. Are you behind a corporate network?

**UPDATE:**

As a response to author's comment. There are 2 ways to save file to Parse.com:

1. Using REST API
2. Using simple HTTP POST request

**First method**

I prefer using HTML5 file field to handle the file for me. It allows users to choose a file.

```js
var videoFile = document.getElementById("your-file");

if (videoFile.files.length > 0) {
  var parseFile = new Parse.File("myVideo.3gp", videoFile.files[0]);
}

parseFile.save().then(function() {
  // Success
}, function(error) {
  // Error: alert() or log()
  console.log(error);
});
```

```html
<input id="your-file" type="file" />
```

**Second method:**

Make a POST request like so or read the docs [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#files).

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: video/3gp" \
  --data-binary '@your-local-file.3gp' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/files/videoFile.3gp
```

Just do the equivalent of this curl in your AJAX request. Is coding in native environment an option? Or, are you coding for PhoneGap, Ionic, etc.?

Comment: Upon snooping more in the Response section of my chrome dev tools, I found this error: 

{"code":107,"error":"base64 field cannot be decoded"}

Maybe I'm going at this all wrong somewhere. Is there a better way to store video on parse? My app is a social video sharing app, and Parse seemed like the right choice, and until now everything has been easy and worked. Video is not being quite so easy.

Comment: I'm coding for PhoneGap. Thats pretty much how I have everything setup already. I can't just use the input HTML5 element either because I'm capturing it using ngCordova and the user's camera.